# Python Urllib2 Cookiejar with Selenium

Tags: python, cookies, selenium, urllib2

I am using python urllib2 and a cookiejar to access a website. The last page of the site is too complex to handle with urllib2 (it uses javascript and frames), so I'd like to open it using Selenium, but I need to transfer my cookies over to selenium before I can proceed.

I have my cookiejar setup as follows

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
```

Is there some way to iterate over this, and output each cookie? It looks like I can set the cookies in selenium using:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("key", "value");
driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually just iterate over the `cj` object. Here is a simple example after opening reddit:

```
In [40]: for c in cj:
   ....:     print c.name, c.value
   ....:     
   ....:     
reddit_first %7B%22firsttime%22%3A%20%22first%22%7D
```

I haven't transferred them to Selenium in that method before, but I assume you can use the structure you have outlined above.

Comment: Thanks, I got this to work, and added the solution to my initial post!

Comment: @xur17 Awesome, nicely done! I'll have to keep that in mind for future Selenium stuff.